# Finding a PA cut in a nonstandard model of PA

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

For a certain project I am currently working on, I need to be able to find PA cuts in nonstandard models of PA, in desirable intervals. For example, I wonder if the following is true, where $\newcommand\PA{\text{PA}}\PA_k$ refers to the theory with only $\Sigma_k$ induction.

**Question.** If $M$ is a model of $\PA$ in which $\PA_{k-1}$ is consistent, but $\PA_k$ is not (so $k$ is nonstandard), then is there a $\PA$ cut in $M$ above $k$ in which $\PA_k$ is consistent?

That is, I want to cut $M$ below the first proof of a contradiction in $\PA_k$, but above $k$, and have $\PA+\text{Con}(\PA_k)$.

Alternatively, is there some other $\Sigma_1$ property of $k$, other than $\neg\text{Con}(\PA_k)$, such that I can always find a $\PA$ cut in $M$ between $k$ and the witness of that property? Kameryn Williams suggested that the Paris-Harrington result may provide this, since it is designed to ensure $\PA$ cuts below the corresponding PH-Ramsey number. But I would need, however, that one can always end-extend the model so as to make the $\Sigma_1$ property true. Does the PH construction have both these features?

With the consistency statements, for example, for any nonstandard $k$ in any model $M$ of $\PA$, there is always an end-extension of $M$ to a model of $\PA$ with $\neg\text{Con}(\PA_k)$.

Comment: If it helps, feel free to assume that$M$ is countable.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\Sigma_k$ fragment of PA"? Taken literally, this would mean that all the PA_k theories are equiconsistent with PA (provably in a weak base theory), hence no k as in the question exists.

Comment: I'm flexible about what $\PA_k$ should mean, but it would be natural to take it as $\Sigma_k$-induction, or simply as the first $k$ axioms of $\PA$, or as the $\Sigma_k$ assertions that are axioms of $\PA$. Since $k$ is nonstandard here, and the cut is taken in the meta theory, I'm not sure what equiconsistency you have in mind. Any model of PA satisfies $\text{Con}(\PA_k)$ for every standard $k$.

Comment: If $\pi$ be the first proof of contradiction of $PA_k$, how much $\pi$ is bigger than $k$? If the question has a positive answer, then $\pi$ should be bigger than any $PA$ provably definable element with parameter equal or less than $k$. Is there any proof for the bigness of $\pi$ without assuming a positive answer to the question?

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki Yes, something like that is a highly relevant question. In other words, can you have a short proof of inconsistency from $\PA_k$, given that $\PA_{k-1}$ is consistent?  But note that $\pi$ itself is definable in $M$ from $k$ and hence from $k-1$.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that Solovay's 1987 paper "Injecting inconsistencies into models of PA" deals with a related problem.  MR1032531

Comment: I'll take a look at it, although note that I am not injecting inconsistency, but consistency! One can always find inconsistency for any $\PA_k$ for nonstandard $k$ in an end-extensions. What I want to do is the opposite.

Comment: Here is the paper mentioned by Goldstern: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007289900481

Comment: Doesn't this paper of Solovey give a negative answer to your question? In remarks after the theorem 1.1, it gave a sufficient lower bound for $n$ respect to the $k$. This implies that there exists a model of $PA$ that $PA_k$ has a short proof of inconsistency, but $PA_{k-1}$ is consistent.

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki Yes, I think you are right. Could you be so kind as to write up and post an answer to explain this?  It would be even better if you could summarize Solovay's construction.

Comment: @Joel In standard terminology, $\Gamma$-fragment of a theory $T$ denotes the set of $\Gamma$-sentences provable in $T$. Under this definition, any proof of contradiction in PA immediately gives a contradiction in $\mathrm{PA}_0$, by the definition of $\mathrm{PA}_0$. Thus, it is impossible that $\mathrm{PA}_k$ is inconsistent, but $\mathrm{PA}_{k-1}$ is consistent. Since this appears not to be what you want, you should avoid the standard term, and call it differently, and in any case, explain it in the question itself, not just in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for the confusion; I have now edited. I had meant the fragment of the axioms of the theory, rather than the consequences. Meanwhile, the notation $\PA_k$ also seems to be standard in the models-of-$\PA$ literature, with my meaning. Solovay uses this notation, for example, in the 1989 paper mentioned by Erfan.

Comment: All right. I wonder what was Solovay’s motivation for not using the usual notation $I\Sigma_k$ (which he acknowledges in the introduction).

Comment: I don't speak for Solovay, but I think the reason may be that in many applications, the use of $\PA_k$ does not matter very much about how you chop $\PA$ down to a fragment, and so one thinks of it as "the $k^{th}$ finite approximation to $\PA$", rather than necessarily having a specific amount of induction. For example, every $\PA$ model has an end-extension where $\text{Con}(\PA_k)$ fails, for any given nonstandard $k$, and it doesn't much matter for this how you cut $\PA$ down.

Comment: For the second question, Suppose we have a $\phi\in\Sigma_1$ such that always we can find a $PA$ cut between $k$ and first witness of $\phi(k)$, but unlike the consistency, $\neg\phi(k)\to\neg\phi(k-1)$ is not necessarily true. Is this acceptable?

Comment: I'd be very interested in that, if also every countable PA model has an end-extension where $\phi(k)$ is true. (Note, with consistency, $\phi(k)$ is the *negated* consistency statement, so we have $\phi(k)\to\phi(k-1)$, without negations.) I believe that one could transform an example like you describe to one with the downward implications, just by insisting that one is above the witnesses for all the smaller instances.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: If $\phi(k)\equiv \neg Con(k)$, so why we have $\neg Con(k)\to \neg Con(k-1)$? It somehow refute the second Incompletness theorem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant the converse, which is what you had said. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I edited my post and add an answer to the second question with properties that I mentioned. I don't know that it works or not, please check it.

Answer (score 5):

**Q1**

Theorem1. Let $M$ be a countable nonstandard model of $PA$, let $r,c,a\in M\setminus\mathbb{N}$, $M\models r,c\leq a$, and suppose $M\models Con_{{\bf I}\Sigma_r}$. Then there exists a model $K$ of $PA$ such that $a\in K$ and

1. $M|_a=K|_a$,
2. $M|_{2^a}\subseteq K$,
3. $K\models\exists d<2^{a^c}Pr_{{\bf I}\Sigma_r}(d,\ulcorner\bot\urcorner)$,
4. $K\models Con_{{\bf I}\Sigma_{r-1}}$.

Proof. See this [paper](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/scan13.pdf).

---

The proof of theorem 1 uses finite Godel's theorem and some other provability results:

Theorem2. Let $T\supseteq {\bf I}\Delta_0+\mathsf{EXP}$ be a consistent theory with provability predicate $Pr_T(x,y)$ such that $Pr_T(x,y)\in\mathsf{P}$, then there exists a $\epsilon >0$ such that the length of the shortest $T$-proof of $Con_T(\bar{n})$ defined by $\forall x(|x|\leq \bar{n}\to \neg Pr_T(x,\ulcorner \bot \urcorner))$ is at least $n^\epsilon$.

Proof. See this [paper](http://www.math.cas.cz/~pudlak/fin-con.pdf).

---

Let $M$ be a countable nonstandard  model of $PA+Con_{{\bf I}\Sigma_{r}}$ for some nonstandard $r\in M$, then by theorem 1, there exists a countable nonstandard model $K\models PA$ such that:

1. $M|_{2^{r+1}}\subseteq K$,
2. $K\models\exists d<2^{(r+1)^r}Pr_{{\bf I}\Sigma_r}(d,\ulcorner\bot\urcorner)$,
3. $K\models Con_{{\bf I}\Sigma_{r-1}}$.

This implies that for any $PA$-cut $K'$ in $K$ above $r$, $K|_{2^{(r+1)^r}}\subseteq K'$, hence $K'\models \exists d<2^{(r+1)^r}Pr_{{\bf I}\Sigma_r}(d,\ulcorner\bot\urcorner)$, therfore the answer of the question is no.

---

**Q2**

Let $Y(x,y)$ be the $PA$ indicator defined in theorem 3.23 of metamathematics of first-order arithmetic. Suppose $(Y(x,y)=z) \equiv \exists w \psi(x,y,z,w)$ for some $\psi\in\Delta_0$. Define $\phi(x)$ by $\exists y \left(\psi(x,(y)_0,(y)_1,(y)_2)\land x< (y)_0\land x< (y)_1\right)$. Let $M$ be a nonstandard model of $PA$. Suppose for some nonstandard element $k\in M$, $M\models \phi(k)$. This implies that there exists a least element $c\in M$ such that $M\models \psi(k,(c)_0,(c)_1,(c)_2)\land k< (c)_0\land k< (c)_1$. This implies:

1. $Y(k,(c)_0)=(c)_1$,
2. $(c)_1$ is nonstandard,
3. $k < (c)_0$,

therefore by definition of indicator there exists a cut $I$ in $M$ such that:

1. $I\models PA$,
2. $k\in I$,
3. $(c)_0\not \in I$, and hence $c\not\in I$.